# plasma desktop - Java IDE for Plasma Global Menu?

Tags: java, kde, plasma, ide, globalmenu

I installed KDE Plasma Desktop and I really like it. I like the global menu, but i noticed that so many apps are not compatible with it.

For Java coding, I have always used Eclipse, but even with Jayatana global menu it's not supported. Same thing with NetBeans which was my first alternative. Could you help me find a Java IDE that just shows the global menu?
I tried KDevelop but for Java is not-usable (can't event create packages or run mains).

Comment: Which version? Is it the one from kubuntu backports? 5.8.7?

Comment: yes it is @DKBose